# Flipbook how to open the pdf files while double clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used this one but its not working for to open the particular page while double clicking.

```js
var book = $.wowBook("#book");
    $(".wowbook-page").on("dblclick", function(){
        book.opts.singlePage = !book.opts.singlePage;
        book.showPage( $(this).data("pageIndex") );
        book.elem.trigger("resize");
    });
```

Comment: this one is flipbook